# Алгоритм для вычисления времени запуска при разных временных интервалах

Tags: c#

Если настоящее время 14:18 ,а последовательность запуска каждые 5 минут,
время запуска должно быть 14:20. Нужен алгоритм для вычисления времени запуска при разных временных интервалах (5 мин, 10 мин, 20 мин, 1 час и т.д.)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать `DateTime`, и метод: `Add`прибавляет заданный интервал (промежуток) времени : секунды, минуты, часы, дни, месяцы, годы

```
var TimeNow = DateTime.Now;
var interval = 10;
var NextTime = TimeNow.AddMinutes(interval);
Console.WriteLine(NextTime.ToShortTimeString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

Метод входные параметры: `i`  интервал в минутах, `t` время окончания.

```
private static void GetNextTime(int i, DateTime t)
{
    var NextTime = DateTime.Now;
    while(NextTime < t)
    {
        NextTime = NextTime.AddMinutes(i);
        Console.WriteLine(NextTime.ToShortTimeString());
    }   
}
```

Использование:

```
var EndTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
GetNextTime(10, EndTime);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Возьмём за базу количество минут с начала суток, найдём текущее время в минутах

```
int fullmin = ahours * 60 + aminutes
int fullinterval = interval_hours * 60 + interval_minutes
```

Тогда следующее время срабатывания будет (деление целочисленное)

```
next =  fullinterval * ((fullmin  + fullinterval - 1) /  fullinterval)
next_hours = next / 60
next_hours =  next_hours % 24  // если возможен переход через границу суток
next_minutes = next % 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Тяжеловато вопрос сформулирован...
Если вам требуется кратность времени по минутам, 
то используйте кратность минут предварительно перебрав 
числа следующие после 14:18 (в вашем случае)
Т.е. перебираем 19, 20, 21... Число 19 определяем из
количества минут. Пусть m = минуты. Тогда перебор начинаем с 19 до 60
предварительно создав массив чисел с 19 до 60.
Дальше определяем чётность числа и готово. 
Находим время в минутах перед запуском. Часы оставляем теми же. Вот вам и выходит ближайшее время запуска.

**Не обозначены критерии подбора времени**

Comment: Start date to run the job (job will run also according to other parameters).  
Start date = Created date & Time
Date = Automatic value of Create Date – current date 
Time = Round up current Time according to selected Frequency 
For Example : 
If current time is 10:17 and selected frequency is 5 min or Immediately than time that will be inserted is 10:20.
If Frequency is 10 Min than time will be : 10: 20. (00; 10;20;30;40;50) 
15min will be 10:30 (15 ; 30 ; 45 ; 00)
30 min will be 10: 30 (00 ; 30 )
1 Hr will be 11:00 (00)

Comment: мне проще в SQL:

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, исходной точкой является 00 минут.

Тогда элементарно:

```
var t = DateTime.Now; // текущее время
var period = 5; // периодичность срабатывания таймера
var dueTime = period - t.Minute % period; // время до следующего срабатывания, в минутах
```

Годится для любого количества минут: 10, 20, 60 и т. д.